# Laravel merge multiple collections and sort by corresponding datetime field

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I have multiple collections merging into one, then sorting that one by datetime to ultimately create a timeline between the collections.

Heres the catch, the datetime columns to sort are different names.

Is there anything I can do to make this cleaner - possibly attach the foreach loop with the `->merge`? Looks ugly with the foreach loop. **note:** code below works but I feel it's a lazy way out and might be slow with more items in the collection.

```
// Create timeline, sortby creation datetimes.
$TimelineItems = collect();

$TimelineItems = $Appointments->merge($lead->SalesResult);
foreach ($TimelineItems as $key => $TimelineItem) {
    if(!empty($TimelineItem->appointment_created)) {
        $TimelineItems[$key]->created_at = $TimelineItem->appointment_created;
    }
    if(!empty($TimelineItem->salesresult_created_timestamp)) {
        $TimelineItems[$key]->created_at = $TimelineItem->salesresult_created_timestamp;
    }
}
$TimelineItems = $TimelineItems->sortByDesc('created_at');
dd($TimelineItems);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *best* solution would probably be to standardize your model objects to use standard date stamp fields - then you wouldn't need to transform them.

Failing that, you could use `each()` or `transform()`:

```
// Create timeline, sortby creation datetimes.
$TimelineItems = collect();
$AppointmentTemps = collect($Appointments);
$SalesResultTemps = $lead->SalesResult;

$TimelineItems = $AppointmentTemps
    ->merge($SalesResultTemps)
    ->transform( function ($item) {
        if(!empty($item->appointment_created)) {
            $item->created_at = $item->appointment_created;
        }
        if(!empty($item->salesresult_created_timestamp)) {
            $item->created_at = $item->salesresult_created_timestamp;
        }

        return $item;
    })
    ->sortByDesc('created_at');

dd($TimelineItems);
```

> The transform method iterates over the collection and calls the given callback with each item in the collection. The items in the collection will be replaced by the values returned by the callback:

See the docs for the [transform()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-transform) collection method for reference.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I've tried your code with the transform and it does not sort. It merges the collections but does not sort - it looks like it will sort the keys of each collection but when I dd() it does not sort properly - just lays the collections next to each other.

Comment: `20 => Appointment {#584 ▶}
    21 => Appointment {#585 ▶}
    22 => SalesResult {#532 ▶}
    33 => SalesResult {#543 ▶}
    40 => SalesResult {#550 ▶}`

Comment: Are the items getting a `created_at` set at all?

Comment: Yes. `"created_at" => "2017-12-08 21:55:49"`

Comment: Oops- but probably not on both types of objects? There is a copy/paste error in the code sample. The second `if` should be checking against `$item->...` not `$TimelineItem->...` - so those objects are probably not being properly set.